# Время пребывания на сайте пользователем

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Есть задача: нужно определить время пребывания на сайте на протяжении 7 минут. Если пользователь находиться на сайте меньше 7 минут, он удаляется с количества только после того, как заканчивается 7 минута с момента его регистрации, если больше 7 минут - то заново регистрируется как новый пользователь. Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста как определять это время, которое должен пребывать пользователь на сайте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я вижу только один способ - посчитать 7 минут на стороне пользователя, например c помощью js функции setTimeout(), которая отправит json запрос на сервер и зарегистрирует пользователя. Вот так:

```
setTimeout(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
    });

}, 7*60*1000)
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за помощь)